# Trying to add. 8 to previous sum

Tags: javascript

Not sure how to phrase the question as I'm still relatively new to algorithms. I'm trying to build a function that takes in a start point, in this case it would be 9, then I want to add 9+8 to get a sum of 17 then 17 + 8 to get 25 etc, but then repeat that a certain amount of times, storing each sum into an array.

Comment: So you're wanting to make a running total starting at n, and adding n - 1 to it, until n is zero.  What's the issue?

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you've done, where you're stuck, errors, expected vs actual output, etc. Otherwise it's unclear where your specific issue is.

Comment: If you are looking for the n factorial equivalent for addition you can look here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593318/factorial-but-with-addition/593323

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, your function coud look like this.

```
/*
 startingValue is a number, the value you want from where you want to start
 increment is a number, the number we add to each iteration
 repeats is a number, how many times we will repeat the incrementation
*/
function incrementMultipleTimes(startingValue, increment, repeats) {

  // Our starting array
  let values = [];
  
  // For each of the repeat wanted, we will run the code once more
  for (var i = 0; i <= repeats; i++) {
    // Set a value in the array equal to our starting value + the increment multiplied the number of times we incremented.
    values[i] = startingValue + (increment * i);
  }
  
  // return the value
  return values;
}
```

Like this, you will have to call `incrementMultipleTimes(9, 8, 2)` in order to get
`[9, 17, 25]`.